Running a .NET application from a SMB share on Mint (using Mono)
I have a .NET (framework) application that I have been able to run, from a Network Share, on a laptop running MINT, by simply installing the "Mono-Complete" package.
However, what I'm trying to do is create a Shortcut on the desktop that points directly to the EXE. From my limited Unix knowledge, it sounded like I am supposed to do that with a "Launcher"
Here is the issue... the "Launcher" method works with MONO as long as the program is a local copy..
mono /home/Program.exe

I can use the Launcher to open the network Folder the program is in, and double click the EXE to run it ...
nemo smb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Share

What I can't seem to get to work is using the Launcher with Mono + SMB
mono smb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Share/Program.exe

When I try that, I get
Cannot open assembly .... No such file or directory

Figured I'd reach out to see if someone maybe was familiar enough with Mono\Unix\Launchers\SMB to know how to get this to work.

Don't waste your time on Mono, https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/the-end-of-mono/ .NET 6/8 should serve you well in such cases.

Thanks but the program is already written. I tried installing the DotNet Framework package but that didn't do anything. It wasn't until I installed Mono did the application actually run.
